# white space nowrap until 100% width

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I have formatted some text as I want and it works well. I dont want it to wrap till it fits the parent div (class parent). The problem is if I fit more text into "VIDEO_TITLE_GOES_HERE" or simply shrink the parent div, the whole text will go out of screen because of white-space:nowrap on inner div's. How can I make this work both ways?

```css
.wrap {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.ms-player-upnext-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.ms-player-upnext-title-wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}

.ms-player-upnext-title-wrap span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.ms-player-upnext-timer-wrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}

.ms-player-upnext-timer-wrap span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.ms-player-upnext-timer-time {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.ms-player-upnext-timer-stop {
  color: #ed7c32;
  border: 1px solid #ed7c32;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 20px!important;
  padding-right: 20px!important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ms-player-upnext-playnow {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-100%, -50%);
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="ms-player-upnext-wrap">

    <div class="ms-player-upnext-title-wrap">
      <span class="ms-player-upnext-video-title-pre">Up Next:&nbsp;</span>
      <span class="ms-player-upnext-video-title">VIDEO_TITLE_GOES_HERE&nbsp;-&nbsp;</span>
      <span class="ms-player-upnext-video-status ms-status-not-viewed">Not Viewed</span>
    </div>

    <div class="ms-player-upnext-timer-wrap">
      <span class="ms-player-upnext-timer">Video will play automatically in:</span>
      <span class="ms-player-upnext-timer-time">&nbsp;10s&nbsp;</span>
      <span class="ms-player-upnext-timer-stop">Stop</span>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your problem is not clear to me. However, if what you want is that the text in  `ms-player-upnext-title-wrap` and `ms-player-upnext-timer-wrap` to wrap only when it touches the page borders, simply remove every `white-space: nowrap;` from your code.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding you're asking, but it seems like you want the text to not wrap until the viewport is smaller than the width of your `div.ms-player-upnext-wrap`? Like one comment says, you could remove every occurrence of `white-space: nowrap`. Is there a reason you need those?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zfbfe41h/